# How to link SearchBar and CollectionView?

Tags: ios, xcode, uicollectionview, uisearchbar

Good day. Tell me how to add to SearchBar CollectionView? Tried and through the cell and through the Reusable View - xcode error:

> Illegal Configuration: Connection "searchBar" cannot have a prototype
>   object as its destination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1 - Adding Xib file**

- **Right click** on the folder you want to add the Xib > **New File** > **User Interface** > **Empty**;
- Drag a **UICollectionViewCell**;
- Drag the **controller** you want to use;

**2 - Adding a class to the UICollectionViewCell**;

- **Right click** on the folder you want to  add the class > **New File** > **Cocoa Touch** > Choose **UICollectionViewCell** on **Subclass Off**;
- Give a name to your class;

**3 - Connect the UICollectionViewCell to the new class**

- Back to **.xib** file, select the cell frame (it should become blue)
- Give a **Identifier** to your cell;
- Connect the created class on **Custom Class**
- Make te **OUTLET** to your controller

**4 - Using the xib on your collectionView**

- Right after setting your **collectionView** **dataSource** and **delegate**, **register** the **xib** created to user whenever you want.

  ```
  self.collectionView.dataSource = self;

  self.collectionView.delegate = self;

  [self.collectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"YourXibNameGoesHere" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"YourIdentifierGoesHere"];
  ```
- Use the cell as you are used to.

  ```
  -(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

      YourCellClass *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"YourCellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];

      return cell;
   }
  ```

You can also manage to create a local variable of your cell.

I hope it helped! :D

Comment: How to add a ReusableView in the CollectionView using xib?

Comment: The exact same thing. Instead of adding a **UICollectionViewCell** to the Xib file, add a **UICollectionReusableView**.

Also, remember to create a class by subclassing a **UICollectionReusableView**.

Also, remember to use `[self.collectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"YourReusableViewXibNameGoesHere" bundle:nil] forSupplementaryViewOfKind:**(UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader OR UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader GOES HERE)** withReuseIdentifier:@"yourReusableViewXibIdentifierGoesHere"];` to register the ReusableView. Create a local variable of your view, initialize it once.

Comment: OK. I added in ReusableView SearchBar, but an error: `invalid nib registered for identifier (ReusableView) - nib must contain exactly one top level object which must be a UICollectionReusableView instance`. How to fix it?

Comment: Create your own class subclassing a **UICollectionReusableView**, on the **interface builder**, select the cell and type the name of your new class on the **Custom Class** field.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is extend `UIView` and have two subviews within it. One, a `UISearchBar` and below it, a `UICollectionView`. You can implement the relevant delegates of the `UISearchBar` and `UICollectionView` and place this whole view wherever you want.

You can do this through xib very easily.